# I can't set the navbar of a template with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm changing a website. I'm a graphic designer and I'm a little bit noobish at coding.

[This is the website](http://futurogames.it/) I'm talking about. I need to fix the navbar and make it higher (I need logo to fit it in completely).

I googled, trying to find a solution, I read a lot of things, I already tried to change something in Bootstrap or CSS files but nothing happened.

EDIT:

```
<header id="topNav" style="height: 81px;"><!-- remove class="topHead" if no topHead used! -->
        <div class="container">
```

Comment: please add some code, or working snippet to this question

Comment: This doesn't look like a bootstrap header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change logo image style to and test

```
style="max-height:100%; width:auto; "
```

In the following line of the file catalog/view/assets/js/scripts.js 
change line-height: value;

```
jQuery('header#topNav a.logo').stop().animate({ 'line-height':'50px', 'margin-top':'0'},400);
```

Comment: it could be a solution, but the logo it's too small this way..

Comment: The answer was updated . Check now

Answer (score 0):

@onlinewebsite, you gave me a hint.

```
function topMain() {
    var _scrollTop = jQuery(document).scrollTop();

    if(window.topNavSmall === false && _scrollTop > 0) {

        jQuery('header#topNav div.nav-main-collapse').addClass('topFix');
        jQuery('#topNav').stop().animate({ 'height':'95px'},400);
        jQuery('header#topNav div.nav-main-collapse').stop().animate({ 'margin-top':'6px'},400);
        jQuery('header#topNav button').stop().animate({ 'margin-top':'0'},100);
        jQuery('header#topNav a.logo').stop().animate({ 'margin-top':'-10px'},400);

        if(jQuery('#header_shadow').length > 0) {
            jQuery('#header_shadow').stop().animate({ 'top':window._headHeightSmall + 'px'},400);/* just a little visible */
        }

        window.topNavSmall = true;
    } 

    if(window.topNavSmall === true && _scrollTop < 3) {
        jQuery('header#topNav div.nav-main-collapse').removeClass('topFix');
        jQuery('#topNav').stop().animate({ 'height':'105px'},400);
        jQuery('header#topNav div.nav-main-collapse').stop().animate({ 'margin-top':'16px'},400);
        jQuery('header#topNav button').stop().animate({ 'margin-top':'8px'},100);
        jQuery('header#topNav a.logo').stop().animate({ 'line-height':'105px', 'margin-top':'0'},400);

        if(jQuery('#header_shadow').length > 0) {
            jQuery('#header_shadow').stop().animate({ 'top':window._headHeight + 'px'},400);
        }

        window.topNavSmall = false;
    }
}
```

Now it works perfectly.